Mixed model for repeated measures logistic regression?
I ran an experiment where participants were randomly assigned to one of two conditions (control vs. treatment). In both conditions they had to make 8 binary choices. That is they were presented two options from which they had to choose one, but they did it for 4 different product categories and for every product category 2 times, so in total 8 times. For example one of the product categories is hotels where they had to choose one of two hotels of which one was of higher quality and had a higher price, and another category is motels where they had to do the same.
In the control condition they saw a review about the quality, but not a star rating, whereas in the treatment condition they saw the same review but with a matching star rating. I want to test whether the presence of the star rating has an influence on the choice, that is the presence of the star rating is the independent variable.
So quality rating is as a between-subjects factor, product category a within-subjects factor, and choice (1 = high quality, 0 = low quality) is the dependent variable.
Since there are multiple binary choices for each participant, I assume I have to use a repeated measures (binary) logistic regression. I think my options are a generalized linear model (GLM) with logit link function as a fixed effects model, or a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) with logit link function as a model with random and fixed effects.
I think that a GLMM would be more appropriate, because the choices for each individual are probably correlated/not independent of each other, for example since they might be generally more focused on quality and also as all 4 product categories are shown 2 times and further might generally (without having any quality information) be perceived as more qualitative.
My questions now are:

Is my thinking correct? Is there a way to test if the mixed effects model (GLMM) is more appropriate than the fixed effects model (GLM)?
Are there any other models to test this? While doing some research, I came across the term generalized estimating equations (GEE) but I did not understand the difference to the above mentioned models. Would this also be an option?
If I assumed correctly that GLMM is the most suitable option, is there a good reference (any book or paper) that deals with the model?

